# shell command to delete all directories with empty __init__.py file

Tags: linux, shell

I'm looking for a command for Linux shell, that will recursively delete all directories containing **just** empty `__init__.py` file and/or other empty directories. So if any file in that directory actually contains at least one byte, it shouldn't be removed.

So, in other words, remove all empty python modules recursively.
Please note, that if directory contains anything else but empty **init**.py file - it shouldn't be deleted.

What i've found/tried so far was:

```
find . -type d -empty -delete
```

And

```
find .  -type d -size -5k -delete
```

And

```
find .  -type d -size 0 -delete
```

First one deletes directories without files(in my example, they contain empty **init**.py file.

Second one somewhy captures all directories

Third doesn't capture anything

Comment: Something like **for f in $(find . -name \__init_\_.py -type f -size 0); do [ $(ls ${f%/*} | wc -l) = 1 ] && rm -rf ${f%/*}; done**

Answer (score 1):

It may be possible to do this with one complicated `find` command, but it's more manageable if you break it up into stages:

1. Delete empty `__init__.py` files.
2. Delete empty directories.

If you do this bottom up using `-depth` then it'll naturally remove directories containing only empty init files and/or nested empty directories.

```
find -depth '(' -type d -o -name __init__.py ')' -print0 |
    while IFS= read -d '' -r path; do
        [[ -f $path && ! -s $path ]] && (($(ls -A1 "$(dirname "$path")" | wc -l) == 1)) && rm "$path"
        rmdir "$path" 2> /dev/null || :
    done
```

Steps:

1. Use `-depth` to process children before parents.
2. Find directories and `__init__.py`s.
3. Process each match in a loop. `-print0` pairs up with `read -d ''` to make sure we handle paths with spaces and newlines properly.
4. The only files we matched were `__init__.py`, so `[[ -f && ! -s ]]` matches empty init files. `(($(ls -A1 "$(dirname "$path")" | wc -l) == 1))` checks that the init file is the only one in its directory. If both conditions are met, the init file is removed.
5. Try to `rmdir` the path. If it's an empty directory it'll be removed. If it's a file or a non-empty directory it won't be. That's fine: errors are suppressed with `2> /dev/null`. `|| :` ignores the failed exit code, making it safe to run this script with `set -e`.

Comment: This solution doesn't work since i don't want to remove empy __init__.py files first.
There may be directories, that contain some files + empty __init__.py file AND something else, then __init__ will get deleted with no purpose.

Comment: Updated to also check that `__init__.py` is the only file in its directory.

Answer (score 0):

You sound like you've already covered how to delete empty directories with your first find command. To delete any directories that have empty files in them you can use:

```
find . -size 0 -exec dirname {} + | xargs rm -rf
```

Here the find command will get the directory name for each directory containing empty files and then all directory names will be piped to xargs which will remove them.

If you have files other than __init.py__ that may be empty then you can just directly specify that only 0 byte files named __init.py__ match the find command with:

```
find . -size 0 -and -name "__init.py__" -exec dirname {} + | xargs rm -rf
```

Comment: This doesn't work since -size 0 doens't return directories

Comment: Right, I'm finding the empty files, but then getting the name of the directory where they are located with `-exec dirname {}` and then piping that directory to `rm -rf`